# How to display a First letter of Name in image layout, if there is no image

Tags: java, android

Hi i am trying to display a First letter of my name in image layout, if there is a no image. example in kitkat version contact images it will take the letter if we not set the contact image.

Comment: Actually there is no such layout as image layout.

Comment: Trick: you can add `ImageView` and `TextView` both, when there is no image, change `visibility` of `TextView` to `View.visible` and `visibility` of `ImageVIew` as `View.Gone` in java code

Comment: sorry about that,here my actual question is: i want to display name on the bitmap and i need to add that on imageview? how to create bitmap dynamically and add text on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look  to how android does [it](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/184ec73/src/com/android/mail/photomanager/LetterTileProvider.java)

```
  public Bitmap getLetterTile(final Dimensions dimensions, final String displayName,
        final String address)
```

This version is complex with a map to recycle letter avatars.
But by the way you can achieve a simple version which simply creates  a bitmap  with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `RelativeLayout` where you have to place 2 `View`s: a `TextView` for a letter and an `ImageView` for an image(photo/avatar) which has to cover over the `TextView` completely. When there is no image in `ImageView` its transparent and thus you gonna see your `TextView` with the letter thru "image".

Comment: Sorry i am not getting, can u explain me briefly